# What article discusses weightmaps for ai control?

Tags: ai, tilemap, articles

A while back, I read an article on using weightmaps to control ai movement, particularly in an RTS environment. I can't find the article again, so perhaps someone here read it? I'm not asking for a list, there's a specific article I'm looking for, and so far I haven't found the magic query on google to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you actually mean influence maps, which have some sort of 'weight' at each point on the grid. My mind-reading skills are not great so I can't tell exactly which article you read but maybe one of these will help: [The Mechanics of Influence Mapping](https://web.archive.org/web/20190717210940/http://aigamedev.com/open/tutorial/influence-map-mechanics/), [Influence Maps](http://www.slideshare.net/mobius.cn/influence-map), [Influence Maps I](http://gameschoolgems.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/influence-maps-i.html), etc.